# DownloadManager with manually pause and resume

Tags: android, download-manager

I need to implement Download-Manager with pause and resume mechanism.

This manager is needed for downloading large video files or any other type.

I thought about using Android's DownloadManager, but as far as I know the DownloadManager doesn't support a manual pause and resume by the user.

What other Android build-in options do I have except for writing this component myself?
Or maybe one knows how to use DownloadManager with manually pause and resume?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to implement it yourself, bearing in mind that the server needs to support resuming. When the server does, it can be sent a request parameter in order to tell it where to resume sending the data from.

See the following SO question for an example of how to implement this.

[Resume http file download in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237079/resume-http-file-download-in-java)

Comment: I know that my server supports this

Comment: Cool, so what you need to do is cancel the request but maintain the existing data, keep it around or preferably store it to disk in your own part file, on resume, get this data back from disk, and open an output stream to it from the server that is sending the remaining data and continue writing out the bytes to it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this open source](https://github.com/yingyixu/android-download-manager), they claim to have implemented pause/resume, haven't tested it yet though.