# How do I pause or resume the file download in a WebView?

Tags: android, webview, android-download-manager

I made a browser.
By using the DownloadManager, I can download a file but I cannot pause or resume my download. 
Please anyone help me

Comment: Make use of this ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297298/downloadmanager-with-manually-pause-and-resume

Comment: Refer open source project https://github.com/JiboStore/DownloadProvider