# Android : Download a single file in many parts

Tags: java, android, eclipse, download, accelerator

I developing an application like Internet Download Manager for Android.

I want to know how to download different parts of file in Android as it is done in IDM.

How can I get the metadata of file before download and how to download files in parts?

There is no username-password or any restrictions in downloading... just simple download by url.

Comment: Through what kind of protocol?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're using HTTP for the download, you'll want to use the `HEAD` http verb and `RANGE` http header.

`HEAD` will give you the filesize (if available), and then `RANGE` lets you download a byte range.

Once you have the filesize, divide it into roughly equal sized chunks and spawn download thread for each chunk. Once all are done, write the file chunks in the correct order.

EDIT:

If you don't know how to use the `RANGE` header, here's another SO answer that explains how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6323043/1355166

Comment: is there any function in android to implement this??

Comment: Yes, I have edited the answer to include a link to another answer.