# Android: Zip is downloaded from Server and not getting Unzipped properly

Tags: android, http, zip, unzip

We are Preparing a Application in which we have to download a bunch of data from Server..
So, We have decided to make a Zip of the whole data and download it from server..

And it works fine also.. We are able to download File completely...

**My Question Are:**

**( 1 )** Our File is getting downloaded fully but it shows Archieve is Either in Unknown Format or Damaged. **How to download file without getting Damaged Using HttpConnection in Android..??**

**( 2 )** If we repair Downloaded file using `WinRar Tools(Alt+R)` then the new Zip works properly..
So, my Question is **How to Repair a zip File Programmatically in Android..??**

**Code for Downloading zip from Server:**

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;

URL url = null;

try
{
    url = new URL(zipPath);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeOutSec * 1000);
    connection.setReadTimeout(connectionReadOutSec * 60 * 1000);
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
}
catch (MalformedURLException e)
{

        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";

} catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "";
}

if(firsttime == 0)
{
    firsttime = 1;

            if(file.exists()){

                 downloaded = (int) file.length();
                 connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes="+(file.length())+"-");
            );
            }
            else
            {
                file.mkdirs();
                file.delete();
            }

        }
else {

            connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + (file.length()) + "-");

        }

        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        if(file.exists()){

            TotalByes = (int) file.length();
       }

        file = null;
        Log.d("Total Value Received", "" + connection.getContentLength());

        if(connection.getContentLength() > 0)
        TotalByes += connection.getContentLength();

        try {

            in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            fos = (downloaded == 0)? new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/EduTab"+"/"+zipfilePath): new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/EduTab"+"/"+zipfilePath,true);
        }
         catch (IOException e) {

            if(connection != null)
            {
                connection.disconnect();    
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }

        bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];


        int x = 0;
        try {
            while ((x = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {

                 bout.write(data, 0, x);

                 downloaded += x;

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            if(connection != null)
            {
                connection.disconnect();    
            }

            e.printStackTrace();

            return "";
        }
```

**For Downloading Zip File we have referred this link:**

[Resume http file download in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237079/resume-http-file-download-in-java)

Any further help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got the answer..

Actually **file was not getting properly saved on SDCard..**
The Reason behind that was `BufferedOutputStream object "bos"` **was not closed** at the end of the Code, because of that ***some bytes where not added to the actual file.. and the Zip showed corrupted while extracting it...***

Just added `bos.close()` at the end of the while loop..
 No need to call `bos.flush(),` As the `close() function` automatically flush the bytes to the actual file before closing the `BufferedOutputStream`..