# Download file with pause and resume button?

Tags: android, android-download-manager, resume-download

I've googled much and I don't find my solution about two pause and resume button.
I use from  [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)  and  [this](http://sunil-android.blogspot.nl/2013/01/pass-data-from-service-to-activity.html) . 
But I don't know how implement pause and resume capability and set what to my pause and resume button onclick event:

```
pausebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopdownload(); AND resumedownload(); <------
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop download call

```
downloadTask.cancel(false);
```

To support resuming download you can use the code from [Resume http file download in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237079/resume-http-file-download-in-java/6323043#6323043):

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
if(ISSUE_DOWNLOAD_STATUS.intValue()==ECMConstant.ECM_DOWNLOADING){
    File file=new File(DESTINATION_PATH);
    if(file.exists()){
         downloaded = (int) file.length();
         connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes="+(file.length())+"-");
    }
}else{
    connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");
}
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
progressBar.setMax(connection.getContentLength());
in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
fos=(downloaded==0)? new FileOutputStream(DESTINATION_PATH): new FileOutputStream(DESTINATION_PATH,true);
bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
int x = 0;
while ((x = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
    bout.write(data, 0, x);
     downloaded += x;
     progressBar.setProgress(downloaded);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but what is your mean about this line: `if(ISSUE_DOWNLOAD_STATUS.intValue()==ECMConstant.ECM_DOWNLOADING)`

Comment: It means that you save your download status somewhere, so when you start/resume download you check if you've already downloaded something or not. You should replace this with your own flag/whatever, this code is just a hint how you could do this. Also check the original question I posted a link for.

Comment: My stop code work fine, thanks. But about the resume func, If I've understood what you mean correctly, I must have this code: `new DownloadTask(this, **ISRESUME**).execute("MYURL");` and in if condition check it. Did I right?

Comment: Yes, and inside your `DownloadTask` you save how much of the file you've `downloaded` (there is `total` variable in your code) so when you start task again you pass the current size to the new task.

Comment: I've been some issue with my stream link and its content length. Finally with some edited I doing that. Thanks Anton for your trick.

Comment: @AntonSavin I get `notFoundException` error for valid link and download links