# java/android download library with resume support

Tags: java, android, download

In my Android application user can download additional files. Often the download process is crashed, so I want to add posibility to resume download if file is not downloaded correctly. I tried to find special libraries for java/android, that supports multithread download and resuming of download, but didn't find.
Please, can anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [Sync Adapter Framework](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html). Or build your own solution w/ help of some other [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237079/resume-http-file-download-in-java).