# Android : How to pause and resume Download using HttpUrlConnection?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, android-download-manager, download-manager

I want to make a download manager for android I want to know how can I add
pause and resume functionality I am using HttpUrlConnection class of android
for getting the data.I also want to know how can I access the InputStream which I get from HttpUrlConnection.getInputStream() which get Interrupted because of the Internet connection(say user turn off internet connection). 
any sample code will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Downloader example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6323043/9125852)

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
if(ISSUE_DOWNLOAD_STATUS.intValue()==ECMConstant.ECM_DOWNLOADING){
    File file=new File(DESTINATION_PATH);
    if(file.exists()){
         downloaded = (int) file.length();
         connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes="+(file.length())+"-");
    }
}else{
    connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");
}
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
progressBar.setMax(connection.getContentLength());
 in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
 fos=(downloaded==0)? new FileOutputStream(DESTINATION_PATH): new FileOutputStream(DESTINATION_PATH,true);
 bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
int x = 0;
while ((x = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
    bout.write(data, 0, x);
     downloaded += x;
     progressBar.setProgress(downloaded);
}
```

**Credits**: https://stackoverflow.com/users/705297/pomatu

Comment: Or else try this library https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/PRDownloader