# Java:Download Restart

Tags: java

i have a java program to download a file through https connection.The program is as follows,

```
public class Download extends Observable implements Runnable {
    private static final int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    public static final int DOWNLOADING = 0;
    public static final int PAUSED = 1; 
    public static final int COMPLETE = 2;
    public static final int CANCELLED = 3;
    public static final int ERROR = 4;

    private URL url; // download URL    
    private static float size; // size of download in bytes 
    private int downloaded; // number of bytes downloaded   
    private int status; // current status of download
    private String location;    

    public Download(URL url,String location){
        this.url = url;
        size=-1;
        downloaded=0;
        status=DOWNLOADING;
        this.location=location;
        download();
    }

    public String getURL(){
        return url.toString();
    }

    public static float getSize(){
        return size;
    }

    public float getProgress(){
        return  ((float) downloaded / size) * 100;
    }

    public void pause(){
        status = PAUSED;
        stateChanged();
    }

    public void resume(){
        status = DOWNLOADING;
        stateChanged();
        download();
    }

    public void cancel(){
        status = CANCELLED;
        stateChanged();
    }

    public void error(){
        status = ERROR;
        stateChanged();
    }

    private String getFileName(URL url){
        String filepath = url.getFile(); 
        int slashIndex = filepath.lastIndexOf("/");
        String fileName = filepath.substring(slashIndex+1,filepath.length());
        String downloadPath = location+"/"+fileName;
        return downloadPath;
     }

    private void download(){
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {     
        RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        int responseCode = 0;
        try{
            HttpsURLConnection connection = getSSLCertificate(getURL());
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Range","bytes=" + downloaded + "-");
            connection.connect();
            responseCode=connection.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode/100 != 2){
                error();
            }
            int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
            if(contentLength <1){
                error();
            }
            if(size == -1){
                size = contentLength;
                stateChanged();
            }
            randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(getFileName(url),"rw");
            randomAccessFile.seek(downloaded);
            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            while(status == DOWNLOADING){
                //byte buffer[]=new byte[3000000];
                byte buffer[];
                float finalSize=size - downloaded;
                if ( finalSize > MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) {
                    buffer = new byte[(int) finalSize];
                } else {
                    buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
                }
                int read = inputStream.read(buffer);
                if(read == -1)
                    break;

                randomAccessFile.write(buffer, 0, read);
                downloaded += read;
                stateChanged();
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                randomAccessFile.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    private void stateChanged(){
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    private HttpsURLConnection getSSLCertificate(String urlPath) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, IOException{
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        ctx.init(new KeyManager[0],new TrustManager[]{new DefaultTrustManager()},new SecureRandom());
        SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);

        URL url = new URL(urlPath);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        return conn;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        System.out.println("Enter the URL and Press ENTER:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String link = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the destination location and Press ENTER:");
        String destination=scanner.nextLine();
        if(link.length() >0 && destination.length()>0){
            Download d = new Download(new URL(link),destination);
            System.out.println("Downloading... ");
            d.run();
            System.out.println("Downloaded Successfully" +" " +"Size:"+(getSize()/1048576) + " MB");
         }else{
             System.out.println("Error! Please provide url and destination location");
             System.exit(1);
         }
    }
```

I need to implement a resume download,ie **if there is internet breakdown while downloading and again internet comes,the download needs to starts from the point where it stops.**

Answer (score 2):

```
randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(getFileName(url),"rw");
```

There is one problem i found. I think everytime you are creating a new file. If file is already exists, then you donot need to write this line. so make it change first.

one more issue is about "Downloaded" variable. In Constructor, Everytime it is initialized by 0. You need to take the last value from where it stops. you can get it by below line.

```
downloaded = (int) randomAccessFile.length();
```

Moreover, you can check this post's answers.

[how to resume an interrupted download - part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428102/how-to-resume-an-interrupted-download-part-2)