# Download resume not working in setRequestProperty method

Tags: android, parse-error, android-download-manager, resume-download

This is my `doInBackground` method:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {

        InputStream input = null;

        HttpURLConnection conection = null;

        BufferedOutputStream bout = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;


        int downloaded = 0;


        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            conection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            if(STATUS) {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myapp.apk");
                if (file.exists()) {
                    downloaded = (int) file.length();
                    conection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + (file.length()) + "-");
                }
            }
            else {
                conection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");
            }
            conection.setDoInput(true);
            conection.setDoOutput(true);

            conection.connect();

            input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
            fos=(downloaded==0)? new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myapp.apk"): new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myapp.apk",true);
            bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;
            int count = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    input.close();
                    return null;
                }

                bout.write(data, 0, count);
                downloaded += count;
                publishProgress((int)(downloaded * 100/ lenghtOfFile) );
                total += count;
            }
            bout.flush();
            input.close();
            fos.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
                if (fos != null)
                    fos.close();
                if (bout != null)
                    bout.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

            if (conection != null)
                conection = null;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I start download task with this code (resume flag is false -> STATUS = FALSE):

```
 dt = new DownloadTask(DownloadsActivity.this, false);
 dt.execute("myurl.something.apk");
```

then when downloaded completely I launch apk file and all thing work correctly and apk installed correctly. 
 
 But when pause my download with this code:

```
dt.cancel(true);
```

and then resume it with this code (resume flag is true-> STATUS = TRUE):

```
 dt = new DownloadTask(DownloadsActivity.this, true);
 dt.execute("myurl.something.apk");
```

This time apk size is equal to `last downloaded before pause + apk total size`, therefore my apk file is corrupted. 
 Which means `connection.setRequestProperty()` not working for me.
 What is my code problem?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428102/how-to-resume-an-interrupted-download-part-2

Comment: @hoomi Yes, Which answer are you referring to?

Comment: The one which was selected as the answer

Comment: @hoomi I used it and get error some thing like `cannot set this before...`. I don't remember it and have no access to my development environment now. Can you edited my code? I used it before `if` statement.

Comment: @hoomi `Cannot set request property after connection is made`. This was my error.

Comment: Isn't that because you set it after `openConnection`? Also another thing, does your server need to support it as well?

Comment: @hoomi Yes thats support. I tried multi link which support with IDM.

Comment: Sorry dude! I am off for today. I will probably try your code in a project and see if I can get it to work when I get back

Comment: Do you have a test url I could try your code with?

Comment: @hoomi are you tested my urls?

Comment: @NarutoUzimaki I do not have the urls unfortunately

Comment: @hoomi http://s1.p30download.com/users/101/mobile/application/music-photo-video/Sensor.music.player.v2.512_p30download.com.apk

Comment: I just tried your code. and I keep getting `Cannot set request property after connection is made` exception. Have you faced this issue before?

Comment: @hoomi yes homan. I got that error.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to resolve? Or you have managed to resolve this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61163/discussion-between-naruto-uzumaki-and-hoomi).