# Disable EditText context menu without make unselectable text

Tags: android

on one of `EditText` on my application i'm trying ti disable context menu after selecting text, after search on google and SF i can find this class helper to disable context menu:

```
public class MenuHidingEditText extends EditText {
    private final Context mContext;

    public MenuHidingEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.mContext = context;

        blockContextMenu();
    }

    public MenuHidingEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.mContext = context;

        blockContextMenu();
    }

    public MenuHidingEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.mContext = context;

        blockContextMenu();
    }

    private void blockContextMenu() {
        this.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new BlockedActionModeCallback());
        this.setLongClickable(false);
        this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                MenuHidingEditText.this.clearFocus();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // setInsertionDisabled when user touches the view
            this.setInsertionDisabled();
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private void setInsertionDisabled() {
        try {
            Field editorField = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mEditor");
            editorField.setAccessible(true);
            Object editorObject = editorField.get(this);

            Class editorClass = Class.forName("android.widget.Editor");
            Field mInsertionControllerEnabledField = editorClass.getDeclaredField("mInsertionControllerEnabled");
            mInsertionControllerEnabledField.setAccessible(true);
            mInsertionControllerEnabledField.set(editorObject, false);
        }
        catch (Exception ignored) {
            // ignore exception here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSuggestionsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    private class BlockedActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        }
    }
}
```

when i use this class i can't select text, i want to disable only context menu, not selecting text, how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: I think you should change `onTouchEvent` and filter it to adapt it in your favor.

Comment: @MehranZamani could you help me by sample code?

Comment: maybe, If i could and if you are not in hurry, i'll do it.

Comment: @MehranZamani ok, i'm waiting to your reply,Thanks

Comment: Let's have this conversion in [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154736/question-amswer).