# Pause android DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

In my application I'm downloading movies from the server. Some of them are very big (4gb or more). I tried to implement my own download manager as a service and it was not quit good. On some devices the app just crashes into itself without any notice, and overall the download seems to be too slowly.

So, I wanted to use Android's default DownloadManager, but my only problem is that I can't pause/resume it.

Is there a way to implement that?

Comment: You mean pause/resume the download from your program, or that the user cannot pause/resume the download in the download manager?

Comment: I want to pause/resume from my code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DownloadManager with manually pause and resume](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297298/downloadmanager-with-manually-pause-and-resume)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell by looking at the source code, this isn't supported (although the `DownloadManager` will automatically retry after failures on its own and after system reboots, etc.).

If you haven't seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297298/downloadmanager-with-manually-pause-and-resume) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237079/resume-http-file-download-in-java) already, it looks like there is some useful information there on how to implement your own service yourself with these capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

I found another very impressive library

https://github.com/Trinea/android-common

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

You can pause by set the Downloads.Impl.COLUMN_CONTROL to Downloads.Impl.CONTROL_PAUSED.

And resume by set the Downloads.Impl.COLUMN_CONTROL, Downloads.Impl.CONTROL_RUN

```
    public void pauseOrResumeDownload(boolean pause, long... ids) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    if (pause) {
        values.put(Downloads.Impl.COLUMN_CONTROL, Downloads.Impl.CONTROL_PAUSED);
    } else {
        values.put(Downloads.Impl.COLUMN_STATUS, Downloads.Impl.STATUS_PENDING);
        values.put(Downloads.Impl.COLUMN_CONTROL, Downloads.Impl.CONTROL_RUN);
    }
    mResolver.update(mBaseUri, values, getWhereClauseForIds(ids), getWhereArgsForIds(ids));
}
```