# How to pause and resume DownloadManager

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager

I know this question is duplicated, I haven't got complacent answer.
 I am using Android System DownloadManager to download file from net work, it works fine with downloading file.

```
 private DownloadManager downloadManager;
 Button start;
 Button pause;
 Button resume;
```

initializing all the buttons above

```
downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
Uri Download_Uri = Uri
                .parse("uri");
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                Download_Uri);
```

then it has been put download queue. when turn is coming it begin downloading

my problem is, is there any simple way to pause download and resume download
like

```
downloadManager.pause();
downloadManager.resume();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254285/how-to-pause-using-downloadmanager