# How To delete the Partly Downloaded Media from the SD card In Android

Tags: android

I am working on application,there i have to download some images from the server for the fist time of running,
the issue is at the of download, if network connection fails the download interrupted at middle,then the partly downloaded  not able to access from the application.
i want to delete that type of files automatically. help me please

Comment: Are you also looking for a way to resume the download rather than ditch it and start over?

Comment: In your running download when you detect the internet stops then in catch u need to delete the file : for internet check you get socketException... try..hop it works

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(isInterrupted())
        {
            // the download was canceled or interrupted, so let's delete the partially downloaded file
            outFile.delete();
        }
        else
        {
            // notify completion
            msg = Message.obtain(parentActivity.activityHandler,
                    AndroidFileDownloader.MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
            parentActivity.activityHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
```

taken from: http://www.hassanpur.com/blog/2011/04/android-development-downloading-a-file-from-the-web/

EDIT (additional info): If you wanted to resume the file download instead of deleting and restarting, take a look at this SO post [how to resume an interrupted download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411480/how-to-resume-an-interrupted-download/3411558#3411558)